# Объяснить работу kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x

Кто нибудь может объяснить, почему в таком коде я не могу получить результат принта spisok, а получаю ошибку? Чем в данном случае является сам spisok и возможно ли его как-то вывести?

```
def get_person(**spisok):
    for one, two in spisok.items():
        print(one, two)
        
get_person(Name = 'Max', Age = 20, Has_car = True)

print(spisok)
```

Comment: Очевидно, `spisok` и другие локальные аргументы функции существуют только внутри функции и снаружи её никакого `spisok` нет и печатать нечего. И `kwargs` тут ни при чём, это касается любых переменных внутри функции

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная с именем `spisok` существует только внутри функции. Ты можешь использовать её только пока задаёшь алгоритм, логику работы твоей функции во время её объявления. Когда ты вызываешь функцию, у тебя не создаётся никаких переменных за пределами функции. После выполнения кода из функции у тебя ничего не остаётся, если ты не задал для неё такого поведения. 
Это можно поправить, написав в начале функции: `global <имя переменной>`, но так лучше не делать, чтобы не оставлять в памяти лишнего мусора. 
Лучше в функции указать `return <переменная>`, а потом при вызове функции присвоить какой-то переменной значение, которое вернёт функция.